# How to transform XML format to another?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a requirement where I need to change the format of a XML message to another format of XML message.

Here is the input that's needs to be converted:

```
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:wsdl="http://ee.co.uk/customer/wsdl"
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
>
    <soap:Header>
        <Ids>
            <userId>11111</userId>
            <responsibilityId>234433</responsibilityId>
        </Ids>
        <requestId>123435</requestId>
        <Token>e34OahuMch0Pai0Nbhr0</Token>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <wsdl:getPersonslip>
            <personId>34343</personId>
        </wsdl:getPersonslip>
    </soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

And after conversion it should look like this:

```
<params>
<param dataType="java.lang.int">11111</param>
<param dataType="oracle.jbo.domain.Number">234433</param>
<param dataType="java.lang.Date">34343</param>
</params>
```

How can I achieve this using XSL?  Not sure where to start. If anyone can give any light on it that will really be helpful.

The XSL I have used here to transform is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" 
extension-element-prefixes="dp">
<xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:template match="/">

        <params>
                <xsl:if test="/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/wsdl:getPersonslip/personId">
                    <param dataType="java.lang.Date">
                        <xsl:value-of select="/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/wsdl:getPersonslip/personId"/>
                    </param>
                </xsl:if>
        </params>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it doesn't seems to be printing it properly.

Comment: **1.** Surely you don't expect one stylesheet to do both transformations? **2.** Where exactly are you having a problem with this?

Comment: I need two stylesheet which can do the transformation.

Comment: Then post two questions. And make sure they are *questions* - not requests for code.

Comment: Done!! Updated the question. Just need a pointer so that I can start doing it.

Comment: Also I have written the XSL for transforming it. But it doesn't print the required part:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use prefixes like `soap:` or `wsdl:` without declaring them first.

Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wsdl="http://ee.co.uk/customer/wsdl"
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
exclude-result-prefixes="wsdl soap">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>    

<xsl:template match="/soap:Envelope">
    <params>
        <param dataType="java.lang.int">
            <xsl:value-of select="soap:Header/Ids/userId"/>
        </param>
        <param dataType="oracle.jbo.domain.Number">
            <xsl:value-of select="soap:Header/Ids/responsibilityId"/>
        </param>
        <param dataType="java.lang.Date">
            <xsl:value-of select="soap:Body/wsdl:getPersonslip/personId"/>
        </param>
    </params>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that prefix needs to be declared. You are awesome!